# Generate XML from Query with a certain XSD definition?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, xquery

I have the following query

```
select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H from View1 where A = '....'
```

And I want to generate the following XML. Is it possible to use Sql Server `for XML` to do it? Or is there any other approach which can be implemented in SQL server?

```
<Root>
  <A>....</A> <!-- Appear only once -->
  <B Id="1">
    <Type C="..." D="...">
      <SubType>
        <Element E="..." F="....">
          <G>...</G>
          <H>...</H>
        </Element>
        .....
      </Subtype>
      ....
    <Type>
    .....
  </B>
  <B>.....
```

Comment: I tried `for xml path('Root')`, `for xml auto` for modified query with multiple subquery and it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes `FOR XML PATH` can be used to get the desired result

```
declare @test table
(
 A int,
 B int,
 C int,
 D int,
 E int,
 F int,
 G int
)

insert into @test values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
insert into @test values (1,3,4,4,5,6,7)

SELECT 
(SELECT top 1 A from @test WHERE A=1 ) as 'A/text()',
( 
      SELECT        
       B as '@id',
       (SELECT C as '@C', D as '@D', 
                E as 'SubType/Element/@E', F as 'SubType/Element/@F',
                G as 'SubType/Element/G/text()',
                F as 'SubType/Element/F/text()' 
         FOR XML PATH('Type'), TYPE
        )
       FROM @test
       WHERE A =1
       FOR XML PATH('B'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('ROOT')
```

Comment: Thanks. Very close now. However, it generates `<Element E="5" F="6" /><G>7</G><F>6</F>` instead of `<Element E="5" F="6"><G>7</G><F>6</F></Element>`?